# find power of two key in sum( multiple power of twos)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

With an ~ 18 years old application users file "cases" and each case creates a row in a "journal" table a data base (on SQL 2000). This cases can be tagged with "descriptors" where a somewhere hard coded limit of 50 is set. The descriptors/tags are stored in a lookup table and the key for the descriptors is a number from the power of two sequence (2^n).

This table looks like this:

| key | descriptor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D 1 |
| 2 | D 2 |
| 4 | D 3 |
| 8 | D 4 |
| 16 | D 5 |

There are 50 rows, which means the biggest key is 562.949.953.421.312. Each case can have up to 8 descriptors, which are unfortunately stored in a single column in the case journal table. They keys are stored as a summary of all descriptors on that case.

- A case with the descriptor D2 has **2** in the journal
- A case with the descriptors D2 and D4 has **10**
- A case with the descriptors D1, D3 and D5 has **21**

The Journal has 100 million records. Now the first time since years there is the requirement to analyze the journal by descriptors.
What would be a smart (mathematical) way to query the journal and get the results for one descriptor?

**Edit:**
in answer to the comment of @Squirrel:

| jkey | jvalue | descriptors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V 1 | 0 |
| 2 | V 2 | 24 |
| 3 | V 3 | 3 |
| 4 | V 4 | 12 |
| 5 | V 5 | 6 |

Comment: please show some samples from this `Journal` table with the required result

Comment: A case with the descriptors D2 and D4 has 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [bitwise operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Assuming the column is `bigint` then

```
where yourcolumn & 16 > 0
```

will find the ones matching D5 for example

If you are trying this query for literal values larger than fit into a signed 32 bit int make sure you cast them to `BIGINT` by the way as they will be interpreted as `numeric` datatype by default which cannot be used with bitwise operators.

```
WHERE yourcolumn & CAST(562949953421312 AS BIGINT) > 0
```

You may also similarly need to cast `yourcolumn` if it is in fact `numeric` rather than `bigint`